# Retrieve both HTTP status code and content from curl in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, curl

I want a script to curl to a file and to put the status code into a variable (or, at least enable me to test the status code)

I can see I can do it in two calls with e.g.

```
url=https://www.gitignore.io/api/nonexistentlanguage
x=$(curl -sI $url | grep HTTP | grep -oe '\d\d\d')
if [[ $x != 200  ]] ; then
  echo "$url SAID $x" ; return
fi
curl $url # etc ...
```

but presumably there's a way to avoid the redundant extra call?

`$?` doesn't help: status code 404 still gets an return code of 0

Comment: `curl -v` will give you the header and body.

Comment: Use `--output` to write the content to a (temporary) file, and `--write-out` to output things like HTTP status. `man curl` is your friend.

Comment: Ah yes, using both `--write-out` and `--output` together gives me 2 separate outputs so something like `x=$(curl -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/404 --write-out '%{http_code}' -o o.txt)` would do it. Yes, thanks.

Comment: curl -v would give me a load more stuff to process, like stripping out the tracing of the connection handshake etc?

Comment: Crossdupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038132/obtain-status-code-and-response-body-from-curl-request  (although probably now considered offtopic) and https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="https://www.gitignore.io/api/nonexistentlanguage"

response=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" $URL)

http_code=$(tail -n1 <<< "$response")  # get the last line
content=$(sed '$ d' <<< "$response")   # get all but the last line which contains the status code

echo "$http_code"
echo "$content"
```

(There are other ways like `--write-out` to a temporary file. But my example does not need to touch the disk to write any temporary file and remembering to delete it; everything is done in RAM)

Comment: thanks I hadn't noticed that using -w still emits the full response first then the -w parameter output

Comment: Almost! on my system (OSX) i needed a newline before http_code "'\n%{http_code}'%{http_code}"

Comment: The newline was missing for me too. But this worked:
`http_code=${response: -3}  # get the last 3 digits` and 
`content=$(echo ${response} | head -c-4)  # get all but the last 3 digits`

Comment: add -L option to curl due to gitignore.io redirection to https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore

Answer (score 2):

Using --write-out and a temporary file got me to :

```
  url="https://www.gitignore.io/api/$1"
  tempfile=$(mktemp)

  code=$(curl -s $url --write-out '%{http_code}' -o $tempfile)

  if [[ $code != 200  ]] ; then
    echo "$url SAID $code"
    rm -f $tempfile
    return $code
  fi
  mv $tempfile $target
```

Comment: if curl failed, ur temporary file will be filled up a lot and can crash your site.

Answer (score 1):

Since curl 7.76.0 there is an option to do this without the extra call, [--fall-with-body](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--fail-with-body)

```
curl -sI --fail-with-body $url
```

Curl will fail with code 22 if the request returns any HTTP status code above 400 but will return the body regardless the status code.